# Why this code provides specialization for **ALL** enums for std::hash template?

Tags: c++, c++11, gcc, enums, stdhash

I'm not a pro in C++ but somehow I provided a solution while porting my MSVS 2015 C++ code to MinGW 4.9.2 to specialize `std::hash` class to support all `enum`s. It there's any C++ compiler developers or C++ pro programmers here, can you explain why this specialization works, although it is Undefined Behavior according the C++ standard they say?

[Link for full code with samples on Gist](https://gist.github.com/slavanap/1936c11c0203c841813e9b1faf1def4e)

```
#include <unordered_set>
#include <functional>

#if (defined __GNUC__) && (__GNUC__ < 6)
// Adds support of std::hash<enum T> to libstdc++.
// GCC 6 provides it out of the box.
namespace std {
    template<typename T>
    struct hash {
        constexpr size_t operator()(typename std::enable_if<std::is_enum<T>::value, T>::type s) const noexcept {
            return static_cast<size_t>(s);
        }
    };
}
#endif
```

Providing support for `std::hash<enum T>` means that all classes like `std::unordered_XXX` will support any `enum` as a key.

GCC 6.1.0 **with** this `std::hash` definition fails with error

```
error: redefinition of 'struct std::hash<_Tp>'
```

GCC 5.3.0 **without** this `std::hash` definition fails for std::unordered_set with following error:

```
In file included from /usr/local/gcc-5.3.0/include/c++/5.3.0/bits/hashtable.h:35:0,
                 from /usr/local/gcc-5.3.0/include/c++/5.3.0/unordered_set:47,
                 from prog.cc:1:
/usr/local/gcc-5.3.0/include/c++/5.3.0/bits/hashtable_policy.h: In instantiation of 'struct std::__detail::__is_noexcept_hash<Foo, std::hash<Foo> >':
/usr/local/gcc-5.3.0/include/c++/5.3.0/type_traits:137:12:   required from 'struct std::__and_<std::__is_fast_hash<std::hash<Foo> >, std::__detail::__is_noexcept_hash<Foo, std::hash<Foo> > >'
/usr/local/gcc-5.3.0/include/c++/5.3.0/type_traits:148:38:   required from 'struct std::__not_<std::__and_<std::__is_fast_hash<std::hash<Foo> >, std::__detail::__is_noexcept_hash<Foo, std::hash<Foo> > > >'
/usr/local/gcc-5.3.0/include/c++/5.3.0/bits/unordered_set.h:95:63:   required from 'class std::unordered_set<Foo>'
prog.cc:25:25:   required from here
/usr/local/gcc-5.3.0/include/c++/5.3.0/bits/hashtable_policy.h:85:34: error: no match for call to '(const std::hash<Foo>) (const Foo&)'
  noexcept(declval<const _Hash&>()(declval<const _Key&>()))>
                                  ^
In file included from /usr/local/gcc-5.3.0/include/c++/5.3.0/bits/move.h:57:0,
                 from /usr/local/gcc-5.3.0/include/c++/5.3.0/bits/stl_pair.h:59,
                 from /usr/local/gcc-5.3.0/include/c++/5.3.0/utility:70,
                 from /usr/local/gcc-5.3.0/include/c++/5.3.0/unordered_set:38,
                 from prog.cc:1:
/usr/local/gcc-5.3.0/include/c++/5.3.0/type_traits: In instantiation of 'struct std::__not_<std::__and_<std::__is_fast_hash<std::hash<Foo> >, std::__detail::__is_noexcept_hash<Foo, std::hash<Foo> > > >':
/usr/local/gcc-5.3.0/include/c++/5.3.0/bits/unordered_set.h:95:63:   required from 'class std::unordered_set<Foo>'
prog.cc:25:25:   required from here
/usr/local/gcc-5.3.0/include/c++/5.3.0/type_traits:148:38: error: 'value' is not a member of 'std::__and_<std::__is_fast_hash<std::hash<Foo> >, std::__detail::__is_noexcept_hash<Foo, std::hash<Foo> > >'
     : public integral_constant<bool, !_Pp::value>
...
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is an ill formed program with no diagnostic required because are not allowed to provide base specializations for template types in `std`.

It worked because in some implementations, providing such a base specialization happens to redirect *all* `std::hash<T>` without an explicit specialization to your hash implementation.  Then your `operator()` proceeds to only work with `enum`s, but that is not why it works, nor does it prevent it from making your program ill formed with no diagnostic required.

Practically, it probably broke because someone SFINAE enabled `std::hash` with an empty base implementation in gcc 6.1: this may be mandated by some C++ standard, unsure, but it is a quality of implementation improvement if not.

The right way to do this is to create

```
struct enum_hash {
  template<typename T>
  constexpr
  typename std::enable_if<std::is_enum<T>::value,std::size_t>::type
  operator()(T s) const noexcept {
    return static_cast<std::size_t>(s);
  }
};
```

Which is a type that can hash any enum.

Now pass `,enum_hash` to `unordered_set<some_enum, enum_hash>` like that.

Comment: Looks like there is only template<typename T> struct hash; in GCC < 6.1.0. I mean there's no body for this template and this means that I providing the body by my code, am I correct?

Comment: @slav yes.  It is still an ill formed program with no diagnostic required, but the compiler generates a program with no error message, and that program (whose behaviour is no longer governed by the standard) happens to behave in a way matching what you want, due to implementation quirks.  Basically, doing this is not worth it, when the cost it saves is to add a `,enum_hash` to unordered map/sets.